How to convert Interval Difference to Circle of Fifths segments and position
I'm designing a numeric decimal notation code model for exploring math relations between notes on chromatic scales and circle of fifths.
The model uses numeric identifiers instead of letters.  So for example
"G" is represented as " 1.50 ".
Have a problem which I'm guessing is likely easy for most of you out there
well versed in music theory - would love feedback on this and pointers to a solution.  My hope is to end up with a simple straight forward math formula / function that can be used.
Description ; Given two musical notes, determine the distance between note 1 and note 2 on a standard scale, 7 or 12 based scale and then convert this distance to the number of segments on the circle of fifths separating the values.
For example, here we have two notes ;
NOTE 1 = 1.483  ( G )
NOTE 2 = 1.428  ( F # )
Distance between n1 : n2 = 1.93 ( B # )
where ; 1.483 * 1.93 = 1.428
Using this value of 1.93, we want to derive the number of segments
that separate NOTE 1 & NOTE 2 on the circle of fifths, which is 4.0
If I look visually at the circle of fifths such as via this link ;
https://randscullard.com/CircleOfFifths/ and from the left column labelled
"Tonic" click on the G note, I can see that the "F#" is four segments clockwise from the "G"
Each segment has the equivalent of 7 semitones to equal a p 5th and
1.496^11 = 7 * 12
But the function, formula I am hoping for is one where I can input the distance
between two notes and get as an output the equivalent number of segments of the circle, in the case of the above example this should be ;
1.93 = 4.0
Where 1.93 is the distance on a scale between note 1 and note 2 and 4.0
is the distance between the notes on the circle of fifths.  The math function
should use the values of note 1, note 2, distance ; 1.48, 1.428, 1.93, to compute
the number of segments on the circle ; 4.0
Can anyone provide some direction on this?

AstroD - you need to edit your question in light of ALL the comments here to structure it appropriately, with all the information one might need to answer. See our [about] and [ask] pages for guidance. Once the question is in good shape, well defined, and meeting requirements, we can take it off hold.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The most straightforward way to do this is to build a lookup table.
Another possibility would be to consider the following:

Chromatic   Clockwise steps around
Semitones   the circle of fifths
0           0
1               7
2           2
3               9
4           4
5               11
6           6
7               1  (13 mod 12)
8           8
9               3  (15 mod 12)
10          10
11              5  (17 mod 12)

Observe that notes whose chromatic distance is an even number of semitones are separated by the same number of steps on the circle of fifths. Pitches chromatically separated by odd numbers of semitones are separated by their (chromatic distance + 6) mod 12.
Thus...
Let C(n1, n2) be a function giving the chromatic distance between two notes n1 and n2 (mod 12). Let D(n1, n2) be a function giving the circle-of-fifths distance of two notes whose chromatic distance is C(n1, n2).
We have

            { [C(n1, n2)]mod12, if C(n1, n2) is even
D(n1, n2) = {
            { [C(n1, n2) + 6]mod12 is C(n1, n2) is odd

To write this as a single function, without an if/then statement, one could write

D(n1, n2) = (C(n1, n2) + (6 * C(n1, n2)mod2))mod12

or, equivalently,

D(n1, n2) = (C(n1, n2) + (6 * (C(n1, n2) && 1)))mod12


The hash table is sensible but am hoping to build this into a function.  I really like your concept on the odds and evens and will explore this for application.  Cheers and sincere appreciation for your feedback.

@AstroD I understand the possible curiosity for a proper function, but since there are only 12 possible iterations, it makes little point. The purpose of a function is to simplify a task (whether it's to actually simplify it or make its access simpler isn't that relevant): while having a function that logically computes steps in the circle of fifths based on the chromatic distance may seem a sophisticated and somehow "elegant" solution, it's not worth it to make many computations that would conceptually base its return value on a range of only 12 possible input values. Remember: efficiency.

In what kind of a situation does a "circle-of-fifths distance" make sense? :) Maybe if someone is using a weird mechanical instrument where the only way to alter pitch is in steps of fifths/fourths or something.

@piiperiReinstateMonica in a logical context it is necessary: for instance, in a program that needs to display the position of the x steps from one key/note to another, or the difference in key signature (more/less sharps or flats). I recently wrote a multi-purpose program as a personal project, that also displays correlations between keys and notes, and finding the amount of "5th steps" is a fundamental function used in various ways there.

@musicamante That's kind of a tautology - a program that needs to display X, has to display X. But for who, for what purpose, does the program display X? What does anyone actually do with this information.

@piiperiReinstateMonica In my case, the part that shows the circle of fifths, with a mapping that returns a specific key/note item based on their distance from C (0), so D is 2, F is -1, etc. In another part of the UI I show some scales that, when hovered, highlight the tonic and following degrees based on the intervals of the scale: an interval->fifths distance method easily allows to get the key/note items from that, also as relative distance for each degree. Knowing that fifth-distance is not only more appropriate in such context, but also simpler for code logic.

You seem to want to use approximations to the frequency ratios: I think this is a bad idea, since you would then need to be multiplying instead of adding. It is much easier to use a logarithmic scale, which is what the semitone count is. Then given a semitone difference of n, you just need to divide n by 7 in the ring of integers modulo 12 to get the number of steps round the circle of fifths. (A fifth interval means a frequency ratio of 2:3, which is very closely approximated by 2^(7/12)). Unfortunately I don't know any programming language that directly supports division in the ring of integers modulo 12, but you can make one easily. (PHP for convenience, but convert in the obvious way.)
function div12($a, $b) // gives a/b mod 12
{ for ($x = 0, $x < 12, $x++)  enter preformatted text here
    if(($x * $b) % 12 == $a) return $x;
  return NULL; // only works if b is coprime to 12
}

Fwiw, I taught my children about "clock arithmetic" at a very early age. It is extremely simple, but almost alone answers your question.

I'm confused by div12(). Doesn't it always return zero, and shouldn't $b play a role? And if the result is to be a/b mod 12, why not just write {return ($a/$b) % 12}?

No, not quite. In ordinary arithmetic notation (or programming languages), a/b means divide a by b in "ordinary arithmetic", i.e. the integers or the reals, then find the result modulo 12. But I am talking about doing division inside the integers modulo 12 (see Wikipedia "Cyclic group"). You can only reliably divide by a number coprime to 12, which 7 is; simply find how many times 7 gets you to the number you want. Your last comment: oops, it certainly should.

Thanks Brian Chandler, your feedback was helpful and I appreciate the time and energy.  I am aware of lcock math, modulo, etc and have no doubt that the principaIs you are outlining are involved.  Would like to ask for clarity on some of the ideas you shared. I have tried to port the code sample to Python and applied your ideas but this has not yet yielded the results I am hoping for.  Here is the Python code ;

def div12(a, b):     Gives a/b mod 12.     Only works if b is coprime to 12.     for x in range(12):         if (x * b) % 12 == a:             return x     return None temp123 = div12(9,7) print("temp123 ;", temp123)

You mentioned ; "given a semitone difference of n, you just need to divide n by 7 in the ring of integers modulo 12 to get the number of steps round the circle of fifths."

Some questions here, so in the example provided the semitone distance on the scale is 1.93, when you say divide by 7, Im guessing you mean either ( 1.93 / 1.5 )  where 1.5 = 7 semitones, of you mean we convert 1.94 and 1.5 to modulo 12 values via ; log(1.93,2)*12 = 11.38 and log(1.5,2)*12 = 7.  Next ; 11.38/7 = 1.62.  The correct value should be "4.0"" however so 1.62 is correct.   I dont think you mean ; 1.93 / 7, modulo 12, this also returns an incorrect value.

meant to say ; 1.62 is incorrect

I don't know Python (except that I have a visceral loathing of the idea of a programming language where typographical layout is significant), but this looks right. Stepping back, the "circle of fifths" only works in 12-TET, using simple integer numbers of semitones. So give your function div12(2, 7), and it should return 2, because 2 semitones is a whole tone, C-D, or two fifths less an octave. A number like 1.93 is presumably a better approximation to a major 2nd, but this does not help. So sorry, but I do not really understand the rest of your calculation.

Quote: "...need to divide n by 7 in the ring of integers modulo 12 to get the number of steps round the circle of fifths." Yes, I really mean this; here is a page with the multiplication table modulo 12 at Wolfram - https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=multiplication+table+modulo+%5B%2F%2Fnumber%3A12%2F%2F%5D - to divide by 7, you look along the 7 row until you find the numerator, then the number of the column is the answer.
